# Avoid changing Visualforce page URL

Tags: visualforce

The Visualforce page has

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit"/>
```

The submit method returns void.

```
public void submit()
```

Now the page has certain URL parameters, the submit method correctly possesses them and works as expected except that while returning, it deletes URL parameters.

The URL '/apex/pageName?var1=abcd&var2=pqrs' becomes '/apex/pageName'. The parameters are gone. Problem with this is when user refreshes the page, it doesn't work as expected as url parameters are not there.

When I change submit method to return PageReference of current page, it rewrites URL with URL parameters + view state which looks unclean.

```
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
```

How can we ensure that URL parameters are not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not redirecting the page then you should use rerender attribute.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" rerender ="form"/>
```

Just give outer form the Id and then rerender it instead of refreshing the complete page,. It will not remove URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce Docs:

> When a redirect occurs the controller **clears** the context state.
>   Consequently we need to reset the query string parameter in the
>   PageReference's parameter map.

Thus your code will be.

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
pageRef.getParameters().put('var1', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('var1'));
pageRef.getParameters().put('var2', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('var2'));
return pageRef;
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm

Comment: The parameters are still there, just hidden in a form post. They're not actually redirecting anywhere, that's just how VF works.

Comment: But when the user refreshes by clicking browser button, they would be lost unless theya re in URL params?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on how the user refreshes, honestly. Either way, it isn't as simple as writing Apex code to fix in this case.